# a man got transferred to cultivation world with the system he made

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation, martial-arts

This is a manga about a guy who is from Earth but transferred to a cultivation world with a system he made.  When he opened his eyes he found that he is a master and all disciples are very strong.

His hair colour is black and he got transferred while when he completed his project of making a system and got heart attack and then he got transferred to cultivation and i think it probably a Chinese manhua.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any character or place names?  Was there anything distinctive about the art or character portrayals?

Comment: No I don't recall any character or place name and I remember that I readed it  in 2022 that it had chapter like 1 to 14 or 16

Comment: This is very bare on details. Do you remember anything about ethnicity? Hair color? How he got transferred? (Was it Truck-kun?) If it seemed like the story was originally in Japanese, Korean, Chinese, or English? How was the grammar and spelling?

Comment: His hair colour is black and he got transferred while when he completed his project of making a system and got heart attack and then he got transferred to cultivation and i think it probably a Chinese manhua

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is *[My Master Knows Everything](https://manhwatop.com/manga/my-master-knows-everything/)* by usa manhua. I found it when I was searching for a new manhwa.

[image: Cover page of My Master Knows Everything]

> The male protagonist was originally a programmer, but he was accidentally reborn into the great world of Xuanhuang and became the master of the peak of the first hundred peaks of the Baifeng Sect. The Tianyuan system developed during his lifetime also came to this world. He became the administrator of the Tianyuan system. He could have the ability to load users into the system, and continuously improve his administrator’s level and his own strength. He and his disciples embarked on this journey. hang life…

From the [first chapter](https://manhwatop.com/manga/my-master-knows-everything/chapter-1/) (click to enlarge):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Glad you found it. Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.